# How to fix blurred PDF preview in TeXstudio under fractional scaling?

Tags: 20.04, latex, plasma, hdpi

I am using fractional scaling in Kubuntu 20.04.
When I compile a .tex file in TeXstudio, the preview of the output is  blurred (however, the generated PDF is not blurred when viewed in Okular or another PDF reader. Only the preview in TeXstudio is blurred).

How to fix it?

[image: blurred]
 <sup>blurred output (zoom in to see)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround is to update to the latest version of texstudio.
First remove the existing version of texstudio.

```
sudo apt remove texstudio texstudio-doc texstudio-l10n
```

Now add the [PPA for texstudio](https://launchpad.net/%7Esunderme/+archive/ubuntu/texstudio).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sunderme/texstudio
```

Update the software catalogue and install texstudio.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install texstudio
```

The version of texstudio from the PPA (currently 4.2.1) previews a high quality PDF.

[image: new version]